# Roundcube java script `beforelogin` event hook

Tags: javascript, roundcube

I'm trying to add a login alert in roundcube, but I don't seem to get the client side events I expect. I want to listen to the `beforelogin` event.

My javascript code looks like this:

```
if (window.rcmail) {
  rcmail.addEventListener('beforelogin', function() {
    console.log("Got beforelogin");
    window.alert("Alert");
  });
  rcmail.addEventListener('init', function() {
    console.log("Got init");
  });
}
```

and it does log

```
Got init
```

to the console log, but to my surprise it does not log

```
Got beforelogin
```

nor does it display the alert.

Server side, the javascript is added by

```
class myalert extends rcube_plugin
{
    function init()
    {
        $this->add_hook('template_object_loginform', array($this,'myalert'));
    }

    function myalert($args)
    {
       $this->include_script('myalert.js');
       return $args;
    }
}
```

Did I misunderstand the naming conventions of roundcube client side events? Did I add it in the wrong way? Is there anything else I could have missed?

Answer (score 2):

Never used roundcube before, but as the doc [stated](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/wiki/Plugin-Events#before-and-after).

> These events are triggered before and after the RoundCube client executes a certain command. An event handler of the before* events can return false in order to prevent the command to be executed.

The `beforelogin` event will only be called when you execute a `login` command.

Comment: Well, this is actually after a (sucessful) login, but the hook it still not called. Thank you for your effort, though.